# Running out of file descriptors for mmaped files despite high limits in multithreaded web-app

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, mmap, file-descriptor

I have an application that mmaps a large number of files.  3000+ or so.  It also uses about 75 worker threads.  The application is written in a mix of Java and C++, with the Java server code calling out to C++ via JNI.

It frequently, though not predictably, runs out of file descriptors.  I have upped the limits in /etc/security/limits.conf to:

```
* hard nofile 131072
```

/proc/sys/fs/file-max is 101752.  The system is a Linode VPS running Ubuntu 8.04 LTS with kernel 2.6.35.4.

Opens fail from both the Java and C++ bits of the code after a certain point.  Netstat doesn't show a large number of open sockets ("netstat -n | wc -l" is under 500).  The number of open files in either lsof or /proc/{pid}/fd are the about expected 2000-5000.

This has had me grasping at straws for a few weeks (not constantly, but in flashes of fear and loathing every time I start getting notifications of things going boom).

There are a couple other loose threads that have me wondering if they offer any insight:

- Since the process has about 75 threads, if the mmaped files were somehow taking up one file descriptor per thread, then the numbers add up.  That said, doing a recursive count on the things in /proc/{pid}/tasks/*/fd currently lists 215575 fds, so it would seem that it should be already hitting the limits and it's not, so that seems unlikely.
- Apache + Passenger are also running on the same box, and come in second for the largest number of file descriptors, but even with children none of those processes weigh in at over 10k descriptors.

I'm unsure where to go from there.  Obviously something's making the app hit its limits, but I'm completely blank for what to check next.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you clarify the failure mode please ? For `mmap()`, it is not required to _keep_ filedescriptors open, i.e. a possible usecase is `open(); mmap(); close(); ... ; munmap()` - the mapping will persist even if the file is closed again. What you describe looks more like you're leaking filedescriptors somewhere, i.e. not closing files where you should.

Comment: Yep, I've suspected a leak as well -- originally thought of titling the post something along the lines of "tools for debugging file descriptor leaks".  I get things in the logs like: I get things like this in the logs: java.io.FileNotFoundException: {path} (Too many open files)

Comment: Try the low-level thing first - `strace -e trace=mmap,munmap,open,close -p <PID>` to find out if your application does correctly _close_ files. You should, over the course of running it, observe filedescriptor numbers to be reused, and you should see actual `close()` calls on previously opened files. Since this is Java, how does the lifecycle of whatever object opens/mmaps/closes a file look like ? Closing from within the destructor might not be a good idea as you can't strictly know when the garbage collector will run.

Comment: The mmaping actually happens on the C++ side of the Java / C++ divide, I just included the Java error since it's more descriptive than my own check for a null result of fopen (which just prints, e.g. "Couldn't open {path}") on the C++ side.  I'll do some strace logging to see if anything useful jumps out of there.  In the C++ code it does only close the file descriptor in the destructor (for my MappedFile class).  I hung on to the open files rather than immediately closing the descriptor since often the mapping size is changed as the file expands, though the Linux-specific mremap could be used

Comment: Thusfar examining the strace output seems to match up basically to the stuff in /proc/{pid}/fd -- i.e. there's one fd being assigned to the files that are supposed to be kept open, and no apparent leaks, and the stuff that's supposed to get closed and recycled is being closed and recycled.

Comment: If you check `/proc/<PID>/limits` for the JVM, are the higher nofile settings reflected there ? If not, then maybe the `pam_limits` module isn't loaded at session start to make sure the nondefault settings are applied ?

Comment: Nope, sadly they're correct there: Max open files 131072 131072 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from all I can tell, this appears to have been an issue specific to Ubuntu 8.04.  After upgrading to 10.04, after one month, there hasn't been a single instance of this problem.  The configuration didn't change, so I'm lead to believe that this must have been a kernel bug.

Answer (score 0):

your setup uses a huge chunk of code that may be guilty of leaking too; the JVM. Maybe you can switch between the sun and the opensource jvms as a way to check if that code is not by chance guilty. Also there are different garbage collector strategies available for the jvm. Using a different one or different sizes will cause more or less garbage collects (which in java includes the closing of a descriptor).

I know its kinda far fetched, but it seems like all the other options you already followed ;)